# Eclipse New plugin project wizard can target eclipse versions, but where is this information saved

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, osgi

In Eclipse (3.3) if you start the New Plugin Project Wizard, the first page has a Target Platform, where you can target a version of eclipse.

Is this information saved/used and if so where?

Also if you then create an extension the plugin.xml is created, and at the top is (for me) :

```
<?eclipse version="3.2"?>
```

Where did this version come from?, does it depend on the extension you just extended? Will it be updated/changed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The plugin 3.2 version is there because there were changes prior to 3.2 which would make it incompatible. However, it's remained the same from 3.2 onwards.

You'll also find that it records the information in the MANIFEST.MF in the Required Execution Environment and (for OSGi apps) puts specific versions in the org.osgi.framework or org.eclipse.core dependencies.

So there's a subtle mapping between Eclipse version and what version numbers are put in these entires; it's not just a 1-1 correspondence between the two.

Comment: I'm going to mark this as my answer as it inspired me to do more investigation based on what was said here.

In the new plugin project wizard if you choose an eclipse version and then create a plugin based on a template in the wizard it will create a plugin.xml with a version at the top related to what you choose... e.g.  3.0 in xml for 3.0,3.1...3.2 in xml for 3.2,3.3 and 3.4 in xml for 3.4,3.5
<br/>

Comment: If you don't use a template in the wizard the target eclipse choice isn't saved...as no plugin.xml is created.  Then created an extension will put the latest eclipse version at the top of the xml...so 3.4 in my case (even for 3.5)

Comment: The plugin.xml is only necessary if you implement one or more extension points. Typically the templates do have this, but it's not solely whether a template was used or not. It's possible to have an Eclipse plugin with no extension points (i.e. just uses OSGi services) but it's fairly normal to have some extension points.

If you open the manifest editor, it will show the extensions; if you add one, it will create a plugin.xml file for you.

Answer (score 2):

Some elements of answer:

From ["Whats your Target?"](http://ekkescorner.wordpress.com/2009/06/25/galileo-whats-your-target/) (for Galileo 3.5, but some applies to 3.3)

[image]

> The IDE is your workbench and the Target Platform defines your Product you’re creating using the IDE.
>
> - What do you need if you have to make your product run outside Eclipse ? (Equinox ? Logging ? Riena ? RAP ? Jetty ? )
> - On which platforms (OS)  should my product run ? (Windows ? OSX ? )

In recent eclipse, the following are including in a Target definition:

> - the location of the target,
> - the list of plug-ins constituting the target  (`Require-bundle` in the `MANIFEST.MF`),
> - the target environment (in plugin.xml)
> - launching argument

But the main information of a Target platform remain the list of plugins needed.

From ["PDE Does Plugin"](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-PDE-does-plugins/PDE-intro.html):

> In order for PDE to provide a development environment that is identical to the runtime environment in which the plug-in will be later deployed, one needs to specify the Target Platform.
> Target platform refers to the set of plug-ins with which the plug-in being developed will be deployed. At runtime, most plug-ins require other plug-ins to be on their class path in order to run properly

[image]

From [RCP FAQ](http://wiki.eclipse.org/RCP_FAQ#What_is_the_recommended_target_platform_setup.3F__Or:_How_can_I_build_and_run_my_RCP_app_against_a_different_version_of_the_Eclipse_base.3F):

> PDE currently supports two versions back for plug-in development. That is, with Eclipse 3.2 you can develop 3.0 plugins and launch 3.0 systems, but not 2.1 or earlier.

Comment: I am familiar with targeting however the main question is what effect the target eclipse dropdown had and where was your choice saved.  I believe it is saved in the plugin.xml if you go on to use a template in the wizard, otherwise it is not saved